# How to erase part of an NSString with NSRegularExpression

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I have a string: `"My goal today is to work out 30 minutes [Last update: May 20, 2013 by Joe Smith] and eat healthy"`

Could someone please craft a `NSRegularExpression` in **Objective-C** that extracts the substring:

`[Last update: May 20, 2013 by Joe Smith]`

I would like to basically erase the part of the string between square brackets `[]` so that my final string becomes:  "My goal today is to work out 30 minutes and eat healthy"

Is the correct **regular expression**:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = 
[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[Last Update:*]" 
options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```

I have seen online some regex that start with `"\b"`, as well as others that escape square brackets:  `"\[Last update:*\]"`   --but with this one I get a compiler warning (but not error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use `*` as what's called a shell glob: it means "match zero or more of any character". Shell globs are different from regular expressions, though, and in a regular-expression context, `*` actually means "match zero or more of the preceding atom". In your case, this would mean "match zero or more occurrences of `:`", which is not what you want.

What you want to do is

```
@"\\[Last Update:[^]]+\\] ?"
```

Note that we started with `\\[`. The "actual" regular expression here is `\[`; we had to add an extra backslash to escape the backslash because we're working within an Objective-C string. This `\[` sequence matches a literal left square bracket. (Since that character has special significance in regular expressions, we need to escape it if there's going to be an actual `[` in the text.) The same thing goes for the `\\]` at the end.

The sequence `[^]]+` means "match any character other than `]`, and match as many as possible". Finally, the `?` (a space followed by a question mark) at the end means that the regular expression will match a space, if one is there. This will prevent you from ending up with two spaces in a row when you remove the matched text. (Depending upon the format of your input, you may want to move the `?` to the beginning of the expression instead.)

If you need more information about regular expressions in Objective-C, look at the [NSRegularExpression documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW53).

Comment: Actually, `*` *is* a regular expression operator. However, the original regular expression would match 'Last Update' followed by zero or more ':'s (ignoring the problem with the brackets).

Comment: Oh, yeah, I misspoke. `*` is a regular expression operator, but with a very different meaning from the shell-glob version. I'll edit my answer for clarity.

Comment: "we had to add an extra backslash to escape the backslash because we're working within an Objective-C string." --Could you please explain in more detail why  I need the 'extra backslash'?

Comment: Sure. The regular expression we want is `\[`, which means "a literal left bracket". Objective-C treats backslashes in strings specially, though: that's how you can include special characters like `\n`. Since we want a literal backslash in the string, we have to prepend our backslash with another backslash, which gives you `\\[`. The Objective-C parser reads this and converts it to `\[`; that's what the NSRegularExpression code actually sees.

Comment: bdesham, you are really good at explaining.  Thank you!  By the way, I happened across a good regex tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html  The one that I had always used was http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html which, while always the first hit, overwhelmed someone like me, plus the style of writing didn't jive with me in the sense that I love explanations like yours that really spell out the last detail.

Comment: Just keep in mind that different regular-expression implementations may use different syntax. If you're getting behavior you don't expect, check with the Apple one to make sure that you're doing what you think you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern:

```
\s*\[[^\]]+\]
```

It will return the data inside the bracket inclusive brackets and a space before them.

After that you have to follow these links to replace these string:

[Example of NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (See example for NSTextCheckingResult)

[Example for StringByReplacingOccurancesOfString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) or [stringByReplacingCharactersInRange](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingCharactersInRange%3awithString%3a)